# jQuery Module pattern not named | How is '$' accessible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the [jQuery latest](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

It is wrapped in a anonymous immediately invoked function expression ( aiife )

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
    // all jQuery code
})( window );
```

How do you access the $ sign , the alias of for jQuery that is so popular?

I thought you needed a name to access if you were going to access something?

Comment: At the very bottom: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;​`

Comment: Exactly. If it is global, it is accessible everywhere unless overridden.

Comment: @KevinB You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Global variables are properties of the global object. In a browser environment, `window` is the global object.

Comment: It has been posted by Raina77ow

Answer (score 3):

`window` object is enough to make a variable accessible. It's basically global object, the scope of executing page. For that reason, you are able to do something like this:

```
window.test = 'hello!';
alert(test);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in these lines:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

In other words, both `jQuery` and `$` are defined as properties of global object. Which make them accessible as they are - by `jQuery` and `$`. )

Answer (score 0):

Nah, `$` is a valid name for a Javascript variable, and jQueryX.js defines it. So you can just use, for example,

```
$(document).ready(){}
```

or

```
$('div').hide();
```

etc

Comment: I don't think this was the question. He was asking how they made the name global.

Comment: @SashaChedygov then what do *How do you access the $ sign , the alias of for jQuery that is so popular?* and *I thought you needed a name to access if you were going to access something?* mean? I'm confused.

Comment: He was asking how the jQuery team managed to make their `$` object global without directly using the closure. See the other answers.

Comment: @SashaChedygov I *do* see the other answers. I just posted my take on the question. Guess it was wrong, though.