# How to use jQuery context parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery passes a version of itself to global scope with this statement:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

as shown in this [SO Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977604/jquery-module-pattern-not-named-how-is-accessible)

Looking at the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) we can see the definition is in top scope for jQuery and defined like this:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

The selector seems pretty straight forward to use: Just pass in a string to select an element or elements from the DOM.

However, how do you use the context parameter correctly?

Comment: You can omit the parameter and jQuery won't complain since it is an optional parameter. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: [RTM](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: technically, JavaScript won't complain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the jQuery manual:

> [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
>
> [...]
>
> ## Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within
>   the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context
>   can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to
>   the $() function. For example, to do a search within an event handler,
>   the search can be restricted like so:
>
> ```
> $('div.foo').click(function() { $('span', this).addClass('bar'); });
> ```
>
> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
>   this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
>   class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so `$('span', this)` is equivalent to `$(this).find('span')`.

Note that jQuery looks at the presence and type of its parameters and acts accordingly.

Comment: What is the document root? Do they mean window.document?

Comment: Document root means the `<html>` element. It means jQuery selectors search for elements starting from `<html>` element e.g. `$("a")` returns all `<a>` nested inside the `<html>` tag. You can do a `$("a", document.getElementById("div1"))` to restrict the search to the `<div id=div1>` element.

Comment: How do you search w/ in an event handler...what does that mean?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist The document root is `<html>` element (as Salman A said), so it's `document.documentElement` instead of `document`